# In C# XML comments, how can I refer a parameter of another method?

Tags: c#, xml, comments

In MethodB XML doc, I want to write something like

```
/// <remarks>Before calling this method, call <see cref="MethodA"> passing zero as <paramef name="MethodA.MyParam"/> value.
```

MethodA is declared like

```
void MethodA(int MyParam)
```

Is it possible? Currently, I have to write it this way:

```
/// <remarks>Before calling this method, call <see cref="MethodA"> passing zero as <i>MyParam<i/> value.
```

Of course, this leads to potential errors as the compiler no longer warns me that the parameter name is wrong if I made a typo or changed the name in the code.

Comment: Not sure you can, and it actually feels like a bit of a code smell to me.

Comment: Yes. Big smell. Why not just call `MethodA` from the start of `MethodB`, rather than putting this responsibility on to the user of your method?

Comment: No-no, the code was just written to illustrate that I need to refer parameters of one method from another. Real cases will be different (i.e. somewhat like "This property is null if you didn't add EmailMessageSchema.Body to <here goes parameter name> when calling DownloadItems method").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

What you can, however is to declare an `IsReady`-like public property and set it to true when `MethodA` is called properly.

`MethodB` should check that property and throw an `InvalidOperationException` if its value is false. Then add this XML coment to `MethodB`:

```
/// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
///     <see cref="IsReady" /> is <c>false<c>.
/// </exception>
```

This way the state of your instance is publicly available, so a caller does not need to know whether `MethodA` is called with the right arguments beforehand, it can just check whether the `IsReady`is true.

Passing what argument would make the instance "ready" should be in the `MethodA`'s own documentation, not in the `MethodB`'s, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. I added the comment to explain that the code does not reflect the actual code I have, I just tried to put some very simple code and put the focus on XML stuff rather than on the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

WAYYYY late here (by 6ish years), but how about:

```
public class Foo
{
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>
    /// Custom InnerHTML:<br/>
    ///   <see cref="Foo.Bar(System.Boolean)">value</see> argument from another method.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// Custom InnerHTML w/Embedded Inline-Code Element:<br/>
    ///   <see cref="Foo.Bar(System.Boolean)"><c>value</c></see> argument from another method.
    /// </para>
    /// </remarks>
    public void NotBar() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// If you call this method, feces will hit the rotating metallic blades.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public void Bar(bool value) { }
}
```

Comment: I think it won't work, 'value' is just a display name here (in Custom InnerHTML). It can be any text there, the compiler doesn't check it.

Comment: I understand what the OP wanted but I was thinking this may be the best workaround in that it will link to the correct method (albeit, not the exact argument in the method) while still displaying the argument's name instead of the signature of the method.

Comment: I guess you wanted to demonstrate how to link a specific overload of some method (if it has multiple overloads) by passing the full signature, not just the method's name. I'm afraid this has nothing to do with the OP's question (OP was me, actually).

Comment: If something doesn't answer the question as the original poster intended I think it is appropriate to have the caveat as part of the answer.